# Ethernet port driver reinstallation

Tags: windows-7, router, drivers, ethernet

I have a computer (Windows 7) which no longer connects to the modem. Up until now has always been connected by a cable. It can connect to internet via Wi-Fi, but it no longer recognises the modem when the cable is plugged in.

History: during troubleshooting with internet provider, they advised go to Device Manager>Network adaptors, click on the local area network or ethernet device and update drivers.

Only wi-fi drivers exist, it is as if the ethernet driver has disappeared.

Have never run into this before, can I reinstall?

Comment: If there is no associated device in device manager the device is likely not present. That means either the device failed, or it has been disabled in the BIOS. Check your BIOS settings and make sure the network adapter is still enabled, otherwise the most likely scenario is the NIC has gone bad. Good news is you can easily add another NIC either internally in a desktop, or via a USB adapter for fairly cheap.

Comment: If the NIC is in the PCI-E slot, you may try to remove it (when the system is down!) and put it back again or to different PCI-E slot. You may also try to use it in different PC. And you may also try to boot up some live Linux distro and see if it's detected there (`ip a` command). And if the driver was updated, it may also require to update firmware of the NIC.